# Intel MPI 2019 always using gcc version 4.9.3

Tags: gcc, compilation, mpi, intel, intel-mpi

Is there a way to specify the GCC version in intel MPI while I use the mpicc command to compile a program?

Comment: Does it not respect the `CC` environment variable mentioned in the man page?  (At least the OpenMPI version of `mpicc` mentions that.)

Comment: How to providing the CC flag to OpenMPI version of mpicc? Is it like

Comment: It's not a flag, it's an environment variable.  In a shell command, you can set it for a command like `CC=something  some_command -args` just like normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working now.

The make the mpicc for Intel MPI to pick a specific gcc I used the option `-gcc-name=path/bin/g++`.

```
mpicc -gcc-name=path/bin/g++ text.cpp
```